# Determining where header file is found

Tags: c, gcc, clang

When I compile with `gcc -v hello.c`<sup>*</sup>, the output shows a search path for `#include`:

```
$ gcc -v hello.c
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
...
clang -cc1 version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2) default target x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/9.1.0/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

**Is there a way to determine definitively which of these locations is used?**  For example, say that `hello.c` contained `#include <stdio.h>`.  I can see manually that there are versions of `stdio.h` in multiple locations, presumably which can use different function construction:

```
$ find /usr/local/include -name "stdio.h"
/usr/local/include/c++/5.5.0/tr1/stdio.h

$ find /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include -name "stdio.h"
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/stdio.h

$ find /usr/include -name "stdio.h"
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/include/sys/stdio.h
/usr/include/stdio.h
```

In Python, this would look something like:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.__file__
'/Users/brad/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/math.cpython-36m-darwin.so'
```

---

<sub>*I'm on a Macbook, so `gcc` actually seems to route to `clang`, although it appears to be a bona fide executable rather than symlink.</sub>

Comment: Use the `-H` option to get the list of included headers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler are you aware if the listed paths are searched in order?  (And recursively?)

Comment: The search order is complex, depending in part on where the headers are.  However, when there is nothing else to alter the sequence, the listed paths are searched in order.  See POSIX [`c99`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/c99.html) command and the documentation of the `-I` option; for GCC, see [Options for directory search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options) and (less importantly) [Options controlling the preprocessor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [gcc man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) page:

> -H
>
> Print the name of each header file used, in addition to other normal activities. Each name is indented to show how deep in the #include stack it is. Precompiled header files are also printed, even if they are found to be invalid; an invalid precompiled header file is printed with ...x and a valid one with ...! .

Comment: Note that the OP's version of `gcc` is actually not `gcc` at all, it's `clang` (must be a Mac user).